# clases extendidas en javascript con ecmascript6

Tags: javascript, es6

Tengo una clase base (`Persona`, que implementa algunos métodos y en su constructor acepta parámetros.
es la siguiente

```
class Persona
{
    constructor (nombre, apellido)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    muestraNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    cambiaNombre(nuevoNombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nuevoNombre;
    }

    muestraApellido()
    {
        return this.apellido;
    }
    cambiaApellido(nuevoApellido)
    {
        this.apellido = nuevoApellido;
    }
}
```

aparte tengo otra clase (`Trabajador`) que hereda de `Persona`

```
class Trabajador extends Persona
{
    constructor(nombre, apellido, nombreEmpresa, direccionEmpresa)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.nombreEmpresa = nombreEmpresa;
        this.direccionEmpresa = direccionEmpresa;
    }

    muestraNombreEmpresa()
    {
        return this.nombreEmpresa;
    }
    cambiaNombreEmpresa(nuevoNombreEmpresa)
    {
        this.nombreEmpresa = nuevoNombreEmpresa;
    }

    muestraDireccionEmpresa()
    {
        return this.direccionEmpresa;
    }
    cambiaDireccionEmpresa(nuevoDireccionEmpresa)
    {
        this.direccionEmpresa = nuevoDireccionEmpresa;
    }

}
```

cuando creo una nueva instancia de `Persona`, lo hace sin problemas

```
var perso = new Persona("pedro", "perez");
```

pero cuando intento instanciar la clase `Trabajador`:

```
var traba = new Trabajador("Juan", "Perez", "Mi Empresita", "Aqui Mismito");
```

me entrega el siguiente error

> ```
>    Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined
>     at Trabajador (Ejercicio 1.js:47)
>     at Ejercicio 1.js:75
> ```

que es en la siguiente línea de la clase `Trabajador`

```
this.nombreEmpresa = nombreEmpresa;
```

que estoy haciendo mal??

Comment: Te recomiendo para el debug usar un linter de ES6. Poniendo tu código en babeljs el error te lo marca bastante claro "'this' is not allowed before super()" https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 8):

La clase `Persona` tiene un constructor que acepta dos parámetros, por ende, la clase espera recibir dichos parámetros en la inicialización de la clase, esto es, cuando haces `new`. La manera de delegar al padre dichos parámetros es mediante la palabra reservada `super`:

```
constructor(nombre, apellido, nombreEmpresa, direccionEmpresa) {
  super(nombre, apellido);
  this.nombreEmpresa = nombreEmpresa;
  this.direccionEmpresa = direccionEmpresa;
}
```

De esta manera, los parámetros `nombre` y `apellido` son delegados a la clase base y por ende, son heredados en `Trabajador`, por lo que podrás seguir accediendo a ellos por medio de `this.nombre` y `this.apellido` respectivamente.

---

Ten en cuenta que estás usando getters y setters **para propiedades públicas**. Actualmente, EcmaScript [está en proceso de evaluación sobre propiedades privadas en clases ES2015](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-private-fields/), así que, por el momento **no es posible tener propiedades privadas** en ES2015; por otro lado, puedes emularlas definiendo las propiedades privadas fuera de la clase o usando [`Symbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Symbol).

---

**Actualización**

> ¿Siempre se debe emplear super al usar la herencia? - @toledano

**Rpta:** siempre y cuando se defina un constructor en la clase hija.

En clases ES2015 **es obligatorio llamar a** `super()` en las clases hijas **si se define un constructor** en ellas. Toma el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 'Hola';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    // no funciona, se debe llamar a super()
    //super();
  }
}

alert(new B().prop);
```

El código anterior, aunque el constructor no defina nada, necesita llamar a `super()` para una correcta instanciación de la clase. Si quitas el constructor de la clase hija, verás que la instanciación se produce correctamente.

> ¿Siempre se tienen que delegar esas propiedades a la clase madre? - @toledano

Sí, porque si no defines un constructor en las clases hijas se producirá un `super()` implícito durante la incialización; por ende, si la clase base recibe parámetros y la llamada implícita no los envía, ocurrirá un error porque no existe un constructor vacío.

Sin embargo, **no es del todo obligatorio** llamar a `super()` en las clases hijas. Esta excepción ocurre cuando la clase base **tiene parámetros por defecto** en su constructor. Por ejemplo:

```js
class A {
  constructor (required = false) {
    this.required = required;
  }
}

class B extends A {}

alert(new B().required);
```

En el código anterior ves como se ejecuta correctamente y esto es debido a que una constructor con parámetros por defecto no requiere una llamada con la existencia de ellos ya que están actualmente "predefinidos".

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Se podría comentar que TypeScript incorpora propiedades privadas, y la sintaxis es súper sencilla : `constructor(private propiedad_privada : Tipo)`

Comment: Es correcto, Typescript implementa la POO como C# o Java, incluyendo genéricos, etc., pero Typescript o Cofeescript no tiene relación con la EcmaScript; no es una implementación oficial como es JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Siempre se debe emplear `super` al usar la herencia? ¿Siempre se tienen que delegar esas propiedades a la clase madre?

Comment: Te he respondido actualizando mi respuesta, @toledano.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, esta muy claro todo, y me sirvio mucho la clase. Saludos

Comment: Me alegro te haya sido de utilidad. No olvides marcar mi respuesta si te pareció correcta.